# why doesn't html file connect with javascript file?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem guys. Trying to write HTML and JS code in different files and connect them. I think I have done it, but nothing works. How it must be done? (javascript file name is correct)

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.js">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h3>Check password size</h3>
   <div class="checker">
     <input type="password" name="passcode" placeholder="Enter password" ><br><br>
     <input type="submit" value="check my password!" onclick="checkpassword()">
   </div>
<p id="message" class="message"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function checkpassword(){
    var pas=document.getElementsByName('passcode')[0].value;
    var x=pas.length;
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="Password size is" +" " +x +" " +"characters";
}
```

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet">` is only for CSS files. If you want to embed a JS file, the HTML for that is `<script src="index.js"></script>`. You need the closing `</script>` tag and note, that the URL is in a `src` attribute, _not_ `href`.

Comment: Why do you think '<link **rel="stylesheet"** href="index.js">' will work? Use a [`script`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) tag.

Comment: @Boldewyn if I use <script> tag, won't I have to write html and js in the same file? I am trying it to be in the separate files.

Comment: No, that’s what the `src=""` attribute is for. If it is present on a `<script>` tag, it tells the browser to ignore the content and instead load JS from the referenced file.

Comment: By the way, the resource that @KooiInc linked to, the Mozilla Developer Network, is quite good. They have information for all ranges from beginner to professional with years of experience. Here’s their HTML intro course: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You sould use the following line to call for/import your javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
```

The way you are writing the code is only to call for a css file.
To call for a different language, you use a different code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="fileName.js"></script>
```

This is used to connect js to html src means source
One more way to do js in html is by using  in html and writing your code in the tag like

```
<script>
function checkpassword(){
var pas=document.getElementsByName('passcode')[0].value;
var x=pas.length;
document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="Password size is" +" " 
+x +" " +"characters";
}
</script>
```

you can put this code in html or can make seprate files

hope it helped you :)

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the script tag to connect javascript with html

```html
<script src="yourFile.js"></script>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please be aware when answering, that if an answer exists that has already been upvoted / accepted before your answer, you'll likely attract downvotes (which I have done here). Please make sure when answering, you are adding something new to the conversation if you are adding an answer that already exists in the context (which you are not doing)